# How do i use MongoDB aggregation match for an array to use pagination

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two collections, **User** and **Post**. The **User** collection looks something like this:

```
{
 "_id": "ObjectID(...)",
 "name": "...",
 "gender": "...",
 "followers": [ObjectID(...), ObjectID(...), ObjectID(...), ....],
 "following": [ObjectID(...), ObjectID(...), ObjectID(...), ....]
}
```

where the *followers* and *following* fields are arrays of users.

And the **Post** collection looks something like this:

```
{
 "_id": "ObjectID(...)",
 "text": "...",
 "date": "...",
 "user": "ObjectID(...)"
}
```

where the **user** field represents which user is the owner of the post.

Now to get all the posts of user's following list, i.e. get all the posts of a user who he is currently following I am doing this:

```
const user = req.user;

let posts = [];
let aggs = [];

for (let follow of user.following) {
  aggs.push(
    Post.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { user: follow.user }, //the follow.user contains the _id of the owner user
      },
    ])
  );
}

for (let agg of aggs) {
  for await (let post of agg) {
    posts.push(post);
  }
}

res.send(posts);
```

where the **req.user** is a particular user. I know this is probably not a good solution but I don't know how do I pass an array of users to the **$match** option in aggregate.

This gets the job done so far. However, this returns all the posts. But if I want to do a pagination like we do in normal **find()** where we add a *limit* and *skip* option, I cannot do that here, because the **$match** operator would work on individual users' posts.

What i want is to get the *cursor* or pointer of all the posts and then do pagination, i.e returns the first 5 post. How do i accomplish this using mongoose queries?

I am using **express v4.17.1** and **mongoose v5.9.1**.

Lastly, my apologies if I haven't been able to explain the question, or what I want accurately since English is not my first language. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you can use `$lookup` on `posts` collection and then use `$slice` for pagination in your lookup it will become a complex aggregate query.

Comment: Do i still use the for loop? @OmarAbbas

Comment: No for loop is not needed in that case, as you will be running your aggregate on `users` collection and your `lookup` on `posts` collection, in your `lookup` use pipeline, in that pipeline use `$slice` to paginate.

Comment: if your issue solved, please accept and upvote my answer bro, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass a value for `skip` and `limit` for pagination
its work for me

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([
   { $match: { "_id": "enter user id" } },
   { $lookup: {         
         from: "post",
         localField: "following",
         foreignField: "user",
         as: "my_docs" } 
    }, 
    { $unwind: '$my_docs' },
    {$project: {"my_docs" : 1}},
    {$skip: 0 },
    {$limit: 10}
])
```